# Transformations of contravariant and covariant tensor operators

Tags: operators, tensor-calculus, representation-theory

I've been able to convince myself that a set of contravariant tensor operators $\hat{O}^{x}$ for $x=1,2,...,n$ respond to a small transformation $\hat{A}$ as,
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A},\hat{O}^{x}]=-(\hat{A})^{x}_{\ y}\hat{O}^{y}
\end{equation}
whilst a set of covariant tensor operators $\hat{O}_{x}$ responds as,
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A},\hat{O}_{x}]=\hat{O}_{y}(\hat{A})^{y}_{\ x}
\end{equation} 
In these equations, the bracket is the commutator, $(\hat{A})^{x}_{\ y}$ is some matrix representation of the operator, and the summation convention is on. The matrix representation that appears naturally is the adjoint rep. So, for a set of contravariant tensor operators, the response is,
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A},\hat{O}^{x}]=-(\hat{A}^{\text{adj}})^{x}_{\ y}\hat{O}^{y}
\end{equation}
The adjoint rep may be equivalent to some other representation 'a'. The example in QM textbooks is that $\hat{A}$ is a component of angular momentum and the adjoint rep is equivalent to a spin 1 irrep. Keeping the question general, suppose the transformation $\hat{A}$ acts on the states $|a,i,u\rangle$ where 'a' labels the irrep,'i' labels the states in irrep 'a' and 'u' labels any copies of irrep 'a'. The adjoint rep is supposed to be equivalent to irrep 'a' (in other words to one particular choice of value 'a'). There are now some other contravariant operators $\hat{O}^{i}$ different from the set $\hat{O}^{x}$ which respond to transformation $\hat{A}$ under the irrep 'a' as,
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A},\hat{O}^{i}]=-(\hat{A}^{a})^{i}_{\ j}\hat{O}^{j}=-\langle a,i,u|\hat{A}|a,j,u\rangle\hat{O}^{j}
\end{equation}
Now, since the adjoint rep and irrep 'a' are equivalent, there is a coordinate transformation matrix,
\begin{equation}
S^{i}_{\ x}=\langle a,i,u|x\rangle
\end{equation}
which relates the two sets of operators. It's straightforward to show that the sets of contravariant tensor operators are related by,
\begin{equation}
\hat{O}^{i}=\sum_{x}\langle a,i,u|x\rangle\hat{O}^{x}
\end{equation}
Now repeat this argument for a set of covariant tensor operators $\hat{O}_{x}$ transforming under the adjoint rep. They are related to a set of covariant tensor operators $\hat{O}_{i}$ transforming under irrep 'a'. The two sets of covariant tensor operators are related by,
\begin{equation}
\hat{O}_{i}=\sum_{x}\hat{O}_{x}\langle x|a,i,u\rangle
\end{equation} 
Now suppose that there is no difference between contravariant and covariant tensor operators transforming under the adjoint rep. For example, this is the case for a set of position operators $\hat{x}_{1},\hat{x}_{2},\hat{x}_{3}$ transforming under the adjoint rep of the 3-d rotation group SO(3). However, the last two equations show that the distinction between contravariant and covariant tensor operators persists for the operators transforming under irrep 'a'. The operators $\hat{O}^{i}=\hat{O}_{i}$ only if $\langle a,i,u|x\rangle=\langle x|a,i,u\rangle$ and this condition does not hold true. This was a surprise to me. I expected that if the distinction between contravariant and covariant operators was unimportant at the level of the adjoint response, it would also be unimportant at the level of the response to irrep 'a'.

Here is a concrete example to illustrate the problem. Let's have a set of three position operators $\hat{x}_{x}$. Their adjoint response to a component of angular momentum is,
\begin{equation}
[\hat{J}_{z},\hat{x}_{x}]=i\epsilon_{zxy}\hat{x}_{y}
\end{equation}
Here, $\epsilon_{xyz}$ is the completely antisymmetrix Levi-Civita tensor. The antisymmetry of the Levi-Civita tensor shows that we don't need to worry about the position operators being contravariant or covariant because both sets respond in the same way. How we have states $|j,m\rangle$ and the adjoint rep is equivalent to the spin $j=1$ irrep.  The transformation matrix is (problem 3.C page 66 of Georgi, "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics", second edition),
\begin{equation}
S^{m}_{\ x}=\langle j=1,m|x\rangle=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
The contravariant spin 1 operators are,
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat{x}^{+1}=&\frac{\hat{x}_{1}-i\hat{x}_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\hat{x}^{0}=&-\hat{x}_{3}\\
\hat{x}^{-1}=&\frac{-\hat{x}_{1}-i\hat{x}_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
The covariant spin 1 operators are,
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat{x}_{+1}=&\frac{\hat{x}_{1}+i\hat{x}_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\hat{x}_{0}=&-\hat{x}_{3}\\
\hat{x}_{-1}=&\frac{-\hat{x}_{1}+i\hat{x}_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Would someone give me a deeper understanding of what's going on here? Maybe it doesn't matter in an actual calculation  whether one used the contravariant or covariant spin 1 operators, but I would like to understand why the adjoint response doesn't care about the contravariant/covariant distinction but the spin 1 response does care.